# Bootstrap Modal isn't closing properly on angular route change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular (the $routeProvider, not ui-route), and I have a bug when I have a modal open and try to change the route.

On the route change, since the modal is still open, two bugs happen:
1) I can't scroll.
2) The opacity is at 0.5.

What seems to be happening is the routed event is firing before my jQuery.hide.

I have a workaround, but I feel like this way sucks.

The modal includes two relevant things.

One is a static link. I did this:

```
// This catches the click on signup from the modal, closes the modal, then
// continues the route change.
$('#modal-signup-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
  $location.path('/signup');
});
```

Basically, I created a jQuery on click handler. Works well.

The second portion of the modal allows a user to log in, and I use a service to call the API request. This one required me to use the $timeout to delay the route change (and it seems to work). I feel like this is a BAD solution.

```
$scope.submit=function() {
  console.log('Submit');
  Login.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function(data) {
    if (data.id) {
      $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
      $timeout(function() {
        $location.path('/games');
      }, 500)
    } else {
      $scope.loginData = data.errors.password;
      $scope.loginError = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.loginError = false;
      }, 6000)
    }
  });
};
```

Ignore the bottom portion, that's just for handling errors.

When I use the $timeout, the modal closes before the route change, and we're gravy.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: you have to close the modal on navigation?

Comment: I get something pretty buggy if I don't.

The modal remains open, and the new route is unscrollable (and the opacity is lowered from the backdrop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use,**`$routeChangeStart`** which gets called on every navigation, or a route change, there you can close your modal.

**`$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() { })`**

**Example:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.run(["$rootScope","$http","$location",
    function($rootScope,$http,$location){

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        $('.modal').modal('hide'); // hides all modals
        $('#login-modal').modal('hide'); // hides specific modal
        angular.element('.modal').hide(); // same as first, but a bit angular way
    })

}])
```

[HEre is the documentation of the same.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: @Tulun, check this?

Comment: also, try `$('.modal').modal('hide');`

Comment: I did something similar with this function:

  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next) {

    // This catches the change if the user successfully logs in and closes the modal
    // before changing the route, preventing a scrolling bug.
    var loginChanged = localStorageService.get('isLogged');
    if (loginChanged) return;

    if (!isLogged && (bunch of conditionals for routes)
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#login-modal').modal('show');
    }


The route change would still activate before the modal closes

  });

Comment: try these, `$('.modal').hide(); $('.modal-backdrop').hide();`

Comment: No dice :(     if (loginChanged){
      $('.modal').hide();
      $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
      return;
    } 

Essentially, if I initiate the path change BEFORE closing the modal, it doesn't seem to catch it unless I tell the path change to wait.

Comment: you can do one thing, in the controller where you are redirecting, you can use  `$('#login-modal').modal('hide');` so that it gets executed and it will hide.